# Nest.js unit testing error , result is undefined , can anyone review and help me its important

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nestjs

## Getting error in writing the testcases for the create method it is returning the result as undefined i am stuck in that from whole day .

/service.ts file code.
create method

```
  async create(createUserServiceDto: CreateUserServiceDto) {
    const data = await this.userService.create(createUserServiceDto);
    console.log(data, 'data return from create');
    return data;
  }
```

/service.entity.ts file , database layer

```
  async create(createUserServiceDto: CreateUserServiceDto) {
    const data = await this.userService.create(createUserServiceDto);
    console.log(data, 'data return from create');
    return data;
  }
```

schema for user

*

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { Departments } from './department.enum';
import { MobileDto } from '../dto/mobile.dto';
import { Mobile } from './mobile-schema';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ type: Mobile, required: true })
  mobileNo: Mobile;

  @Prop({ enum: Departments, required: true })
  department: string;

  @Prop({ default: false }) // Set the default value to false
  isDeleted: boolean;
}
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

*create method, test case where I am getting error

```
**  describe('create', () => {
    it('should create the user', async () => {
      const createDto = {
        name: 'Yash',
        email: 'yashkkb@gmail.com',
        mobileNo: '01200038888',
        department: 'AMBULANCE',
      };

      jest.spyOn(userService, 'create').mockResolvedValue(createMockUser);
      const result = await userService.create(createDto);
      expect(result).toEqual(createMockUser);
      expect(userService.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(createDto);
    });
  });
```

INPUT

```
      const createDto = {
        name: 'Yash',
        email: 'yashkkb@gmail.com',
        mobileNo: '01200038888',
        department: 'AMBULANCE',
      };
```

OUTPUT

```
  const createMockUser = {
    name: 'Yash',
    email: 'yashkkb@gmail.com',
    mobileNo: '01200038888',
    department: 'AMBULANCE',
    isDeleted: false,
    _id: '64d0a8a10a677d194ed3a07B',
    createdAt: '2023-08-07T08:17:37.789Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-08-07T08:17:37.789Z',
    __v: 0,
  };
```

Comment: This is a place where people give their free time to try and help you. Saying that it's important in the title just makes you come of as rude and uninformed.